# How do I get the libxpcom.so file for Titanium Appcelerator Studio?

Tags: shared-library

I'm trying to install Titanium Appcelerator Studio under Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit...

It launches almost fine, except it needs `libxpcom.so`.

I've been looking for it for hours now, I cant find the latest version of it.

I have read that that lib comes with the `xulrunner` package.

I downloaded the latest version or xulrunner from mozilla. But the lib is still missing.

Where can I find the latest version of `libxpcom.so`?

Comment: is it libxpscom.so??

Comment: Voting to close ; OP stated that "Titanium Studio generate an XCOM Error now. Still nothing about that on the internet. Giving up."

Answer (score 5):

Download a `deb` package containing that library from http://http.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/i/icedove/icedove_3.0.11-1+squeeze15_amd64.deb

Open it with Archive Manager (not Software Center), navigate to `usr`, `lib`, `icedove`, select `libxpcom.so` and `libxpcom_core.so` and extract them let's say to Desktop.

Open a terminal with Ctrl+Alt+T, `cd ~/Desktop` then

`sudo cp ./libxpcom.so /usr/lib/libxpcom.so` and after

`sudo cp ./libxpcom_core.so /usr/lib/libxpcom_core.so`

`libxpcom.so` probably is linked to `libxpcom_core.so` that's why I included it.

Comment: Did the trick, but Titanium Studio generate an XCOM Error now. Still nothing about that on the internet. Giving up.